# Is it possible that a React app serves raw json directly?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible that the React app - similar to an API endpoint - serves a raw JSON file on a specific route?

Looking for direction regarding "architecture" of how to solve that problem

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to acheive. If you build your application with Next.js you can use this https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction.

Comment: Putting your json file in the Public folder might do the trick. I am not sure. "hostServerUrl/public/yourJsonFileName.json".